# Reading static variable in Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

Is it safe to read from the static variable inside of `Parallel.ForEach`

```
class Program
{
    private static string _startTime;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _startTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Parallel.ForEach(args,
        arg =>
        {
            Process(arg);
        });
    }

    private static void Process(string arg)
    {
        //Can I read _processStartTime variable here
        var startDateTime = _startTime;
        
    }
}
```

This article mentions about reading from a static variable but did not provide more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism

Comment: It's safe as long as `_startTime` is not *written* from any thread

Comment: Why are you even doing this?  Why are you not just passing in the value as a parameter, just like you're doing for the other argument you need?  Using the static variable adds a significant amount of complexity to the code for no added value and significant costs.  The whole point of a static field is to allow anything to set it anywhere at any time, which *you very specifically don't want*, because your code breaks if anyone actually uses it that way.

Comment: @Servy you are right. I felt instead of passing additional param, use a common static variable. As you mentioned, there is chance of misunderstanding it can create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading is fine (so long as all threads are just reading).

Editing requires thread-safety. If any thread will edit the data, even if the others are just reading, thread-safety needs to be addressed.

If the thing you were reading got it's data from computation or an external source, you'd need to think about thread-safety too, but in this particular example it's perfectly safe because it will always be the same value every time.

If you had a more real life example, you'll need to be aware of potential pitfalls, but for simple reads, it's not an issue.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias nope, he means that if *all* the threads access the data for *reading* only, then it's safe. As long as at least one thread writes the variable, all other threads (whether they are reading or writing) aren't safe anymore.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias limserhane is right. I'll edit to add that additional context in. It's what I meant, accidental ambiguity.